# Existence of the inverse of a distribution function of a real-valued random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

In the proof of the [probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform#Proof) at Wikipedia, they take *any* real-valued random variable $X$ and use the inverse of its distribution function $F_X$.

> However, a distribution function is monotonically increasing, but *not* necessarily strictly increasing. So, the inverse of $F_x$ might not even exist.

Is this an error from Wikipedia or do I miss something?

Comment: I can't believe this! I was reading the exact same article (after reading it in Casella's book) and typed "are continuous distribution functions invertible?" and found this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $F_X$ need not be strictly increasing, one must use a sort of generalized inverse.  Preferences vary with authors, but here is one example (the "right-continuous inverse"):
$$
F^{-1,+}_X(t):=\inf\{x: F_X(x)>t\}, \quad t\in[0,1],
$$
wherein $\inf\emptyset$ is understood to equal $1$.

For example, if $X$ has cdf 
$$
F_X(x)=\cases{0,&$x<1$;\cr {1\over 3},&$1\le x<2$;\cr 1,&$x\ge 2$,\cr}
$$
then
$$
F^{-1,+}_X(t) =\cases{1,&$0\le t<{1\over 3}$;\cr 2,&${1\over 3}\le t\le 1$.\cr}
$$
In this case, if $U$ has the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, then $F^{-1,+}(U)$ takes the value 1 with probability $1/3$ and the value 2 with probability $2/3$, so $F^{-1,+}(U)$ has the same distribution as $X$.

The "left-continuous inverse" $F^{-1,-}_X(t):=\sup\{x: F_X(x)\le t\}$ would work as well.

Comment: Let $F^{-1}$ be the left-continuous inverse. Then, the third equation in the proof from Wikipedia won't hold, unless $$F(x)\le y\Leftrightarrow x\le F^{-1}(y)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb R\text{ and }y\in [0,1]\;.$$ "$\Rightarrow$" holds by definition of $F^{-1}$, but "$\Leftarrow$" doesn't seem to hold (otherwise, $F^{-1}$ would be the inverse). So, if I'm not wrong, the third equation is false.

Comment: The events $\{F_X(X)\le y\}$ and $\{X\le F^{-1,-}(y)\}$ are not identical (the second is a subset of the first; the first *is* the same as $\{X\le F^{-1,+}_X(y)\}$) but they do have the same probability, because $\Bbb P[X\in(F^{-1,-}_X(y),F^{-1+}_X(y)]]=0$.

Comment: I'm still unsure, why this event has probability $0$ and asked another question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598866/if-f-1-and-f-1-are-the-right-and-left-cont-inverse-of-a-cdf-res